# Punishment for disobedient Jewish slaves

Tags: halacha, reward-punishment, beit-din-court, slave-serve-eved-avadim, chovel-umazik

What exactly is the punishment for a disobedient Jewish (Hebrew) slave? And what exactly is the procedure for the punishment, does the owner go before the Beit Din, or do the judgement themselves? And what exact things can the slave refuse without punishment from the master vs what the slave is obligated to under the threat of penalty? Source for the Halacha regarding this please.

Comment: Relevant: end of chapter 1 of Hilchot Avadim: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1363800/jewish/Avadim-Chapter-One.htm

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it has enough to be a full answer. Your question deserves better. That Rambam is useful background but there must be a procedure for punishment and clear rules, I just have not had a chance to review the laws in more detail